# VB.Net Threading and Saving Results

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm working on the program for work, where the user is able to search AD for a asset tag of a certain computer.  If it is found it will give them a list in a listbox.  I have all of that working, but when they do the search the UI freezes.  I'm new to VB and OO for that matter.  I understand that it is freezing because the search is running on the same thread as the UI, but I cannot for the life of me get another thread to do the work.  When I tried to do the search in another thread I can't update the listbox because its not on the same thread.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Function that searches AD:

```
   Private Function searchAd()

    'clear the results from previous entries
    ' AdResultListBox.Items.Clear()

    Try
        Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("GC://mydomaininfo")
        Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)

        'selects the Computer Name property
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")


        Dim compname As String = PropertyTagTextbox.Text
        'searches using wildcards
        compname = "*" + compname + "*"

        searcher.Filter = "(&(name=" + compname + ")(objectcategory=moreADinformation))"

        Dim results As SearchResultCollection
        results = searcher.FindAll()

        Dim result As SearchResult


        For Each result In results

            'this is the part i'm having trouble with
            Me.AdResultListBox.Items.Add(result.Properties("cn")(0)

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function



Private Sub ADSearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ADSearchButton.Click
    AdResultListBox.Items.Clear()

    'create the new thread for searching
    Dim SearchThread As New Thread(AddressOf searchAd)
    SearchThread.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see any threading code in their at all

Comment: I took it out because it didn't work.  At all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I typically do it. The `Invoke` function is part of the control and that passes a delegate to the UI thread so it can be processed in the correct thread.

```
Invoke(Sub
          Me.AdResultListBox.Items.Add(result.Properties("cn")(0)
    End Sub)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: I'm completely new to threading.  I looked through the msdn article, but I don't really understand it.  Do I call the invoke from the SearchAD function?

Comment: Yeah, you use invoke from inside the thread. It serves to pass the function over to the UI thread so it will run properly.

Answer (score 2):

There happens to be an MSDN article "Using System.DirectoryServices to Search the Active Directory" which shows running it in another thread at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx#dotnetadsearch_topic9.

Comment: I tried to follow the example, but I was lost.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around threading.